# Is WordUtils.capitalizeFully I18N?

Tags: java, internationalization, apache-commons

I want to use WordUtils.capitalizeFully but am unsure what it does with other languages.  Heck, I'm not even sure if Chinese has upper/lower case.  We also use Swedish, German and Russian.

Anyone tried it out?

Comment: As Bozho says, from the docs, it looks like it leans on unicode, so if you think unicode's idea of 'title case' is correct, then it does the right thing. But be careful - in German, nouns are capitalized and other words are not (roughly speaking), so if you go round title-casing German text, it will look rather odd to its readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems so:

```
 System.out.println(WordUtils.capitalizeFully("можеше да провериш сам"));
```

prints

```
Можеше Да Провериш Сам
```

The documentation says:

> Capitalization uses the unicode title case, normally equivalent to upper case

Comment: some full-width characters test: `System.out.println (WordUtils.capitalizeFully("ｔｈｉｓ　ｉｓ　ａ　ｔｅｓｔ"));` will output **Ｔｈｉｓ　Ｉｓ　Ａ　Ｔｅｓｔ**

Comment: Rats, I did not see this documentation.  I believe this is the answer although it seems it would be good if a Turk responded...

Comment: @markthegrea it is two years late but for Turkish, it does not correctly handle ı <-> I and i <-> İ cases. Other characters like ç, ğ, ş etc seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese and other similar languages (Japanese, Korean, Vietnamese) does not have concept of upper- and lower-case characters (unless transliterated). There are quite a lot languages like this. The only way to be 100% sure is test, since documentation might be erroneous.

I would be more concerned if the utility you mention capitalizes [Turkish language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) correctly - it has strange concept of [dotted and dotless I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I). German could also be a problem, since [sharp S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) should be uppercased to SS.